# CSS display a vertical scroll bar into a div

Tags: css

I do want to display a scrollbar inside a table ( within a div ):

```
    <div style="width:789px; height:150px; overflow:auto;">

...

    </div>
```

The problem is that the div have the default height already 150px. I want it to have no height defined from the start, and when the div reaches 150px, the scroll-bar to appear. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use max-height: 150px; min-height: 150px;

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry for the "minimum" word in the question. I will edit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with `max-height` instead of height. It will trigger the scroll-bar once it will reach the `max-height`.

CSS:

```
<div style="width:789px; max-height:150px; overflow:auto;">

...

</div>
```

Comment: The question is when it reaches the min height of 150 the scroll should appear

Comment: I think that he doens't want have a height in the beginning and then when he reaches x px to have a fixed height.

Comment: Author just edited the question and you deserves to get the up-vote +1.

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x48gh635/) it should show you how to archive this

```
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.content{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property `max-height`

```
div {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Here is an [JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kc8c4jct/).
.

Comment: You cannot just post the link as an answer should include your code too.